# Another way of redirecting standard output of method call in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, redirectstandardoutput

I'm developing a Spring Boot application, which aims to receive code from users, compile, execute it and finally show users their code output. For that purpose I created a Component responsible for executing code and saving the output in a txt file (via `PrintStream`), which looks like that:

```
@Component
public class SimpleExecutor implements Executor {
    @Autowired
    private FileStorageService fileStorageService;

    public Path runClass(Class helloClass, String outputPath) throws Exception {
        helloClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
        Method method = helloClass.getMethod("main", String[].class);
        try {
            PrintStream fileStream = new PrintStream(outputPath);
            System.setOut(fileStream);
            String[] params = null;
            method.invoke(null, (Object) params);
            return Paths.get(outputPath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.setOut(null);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Above `runClass` method is called by another `@Async` method (so it is working in another thread than the application's). The problem is that changing `System.out` to my `fileStream` means storing Spring debug information as well (which of course isn't intended). For example, instead of simple "Hello world" I sometimes get:

```
2019-05-17 01:43:58.371 DEBUG 9720 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/code/upload", parameters={}
2019-05-17 01:43:58.372 DEBUG 9720 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.example.controllers.CompilerApiController.singleFileUpload(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile) throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException
2019-05-17 01:43:58.374 DEBUG 9720 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'text/plain', given [*/*] and supported [text/plain, */*, text/plain, */*, application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2019-05-17 01:43:58.375 DEBUG 9720 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing ["Successfully uploaded file!"]
2019-05-17 01:43:58.376 DEBUG 9720 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2019-05-17 01:43:59.163 DEBUG 9720 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/code/upload", parameters={}
2019-05-17 01:43:59.165 DEBUG 9720 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.example.controllers.CompilerApiController.singleFileUpload(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile) throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException
2019-05-17 01:43:59.167 DEBUG 9720 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'text/plain', given [*/*] and supported [text/plain, */*, text/plain, */*, application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2019-05-17 01:43:59.167 DEBUG 9720 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing ["Successfully uploaded file!"]
2019-05-17 01:43:59.168 DEBUG 9720 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2019-05-17 01:44:00.101 DEBUG 9720 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/code/upload", parameters={}
2019-05-17 01:44:00.101 DEBUG 9720 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.example.controllers.CompilerApiController.singleFileUpload(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile) throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException
2019-05-17 01:44:00.103 DEBUG 9720 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'text/plain', given [*/*] and supported [text/plain, */*, text/plain, */*, application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2019-05-17 01:44:00.103 DEBUG 9720 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing ["Successfully uploaded file!"]
2019-05-17 01:44:00.104 DEBUG 9720 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
Hello world
```

Is there any other way I can redirect standard output of `method.invoke` call? That's the one that prints the stuff I would like to store.

Comment: If i understand, instead of writing as a log, you want to write only the output into a file.

Comment: @Sambit correct, I would like to get **only** "Hello world" in the output file, not the whole loggy thing from Spring app

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this.

```
public Path runClass(Class helloClass, String outputPath) throws Exception {

........ other code

FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("mySeparateLog.txt");
System.setOut(new PrintStream(f));

....... other code

}
```

Comment: Nope, it still saves the Spring logs. The main problem is that `System.out` is shared between Spring logging functionalities and my `method.invoke` call. I thought of something like synchronising the `System.out` when calling the `method.invoke`, but it's neither clear nor satisfying, because then I lose all the async character.